# Access custom logger in AppModule

Tags: nestjs

I replaced the nestjs logger with a custom for having it also for bootstrap messages.

This is the code i have used to instantiate it

```js
  async function bootstrap() {
  const logger = CustomLoggerModule.createLogger();
  try {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
      logger,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(e)
  }
```

`createLogger` is a static method of the `CustomLoggerModule` class that returns an instance of the `CustomLoggerModule` class, a class that implements Nest's `LoggerService` interface.

I now want to have access to the Logger inside the AppModule and this is what I've tried:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    ESModule,
    ElasticSearchConfigModule,
    KafkaConfigModule,
    IndexModule,
    AppConfigModule,
    ReadyModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER, //you have to use this custom provider
      useClass: ErrorFilter, //this is your custom exception filter
    },
    Logger,
  ],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  constructor(private moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    const logger = this.moduleRef.get(Logger) as CustomLoggerModule;
    const logger.initMiddleware(consumer);
  }
}
```

But in this way, I get an exception at the line `logger.initMiddleware`, because the logger returned by `moduleRef` is of type Logger 
Obviously by trying to access `CustomLogger` inside modules other than the AppModule by dependency injection works as expected
How can I access my custom logger instance inside the appModule ?

Answer (score 1):

From Nest:

> Because application instantiation (`NestFactory.create()`) happens outside the context of any module, it doesn't participate in the normal Dependency Injection phase of initialization.

So, you must ensure that at least one application module imports a `CustomloggerModule` to trigger Nest to instantiate a singleton instance of the custom logger class.

One of your application modules needs to have the following:

```js
providers: [Logger]
exports: [Logger]
```

Also, you're not setting the value of the optional logger property in `NestFactory.create()` to an object that fulfills the `LoggerService` interface. In addition, you may want to capture any output from the system logger during setup, prior to DI. Try:

```js
{
  logger: logger,
  bufferLogs: true
}
```

Then, you need to instruct Nest to use the logger singleton instance in your bootstrap. So, if possible get a singleton instance after exporting your logger prototype and you'll be good to go:

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
  logger:logger,
  bufferLogs: true
});
const logger = app.get(CustomLoggerService); 
app.useLogger(logger);
```

Comment: You can get a singleton instance after exporting your logger prototype. const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { logger, logger});  const logger = app.get(CustomLoggerService); app.useLogger(logger);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).